# How to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7/8

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-7, windows-8

I have a pre-installed Windows 7/8 and I want to install Ubuntu alongside that. When I try to install I do not have an *Install ubuntu alongside windows 7/8* option during the installation (it's missing). How can I have or get back this option?

Comment: Is this a tutorial?

Comment: See this: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7106/should-i-share-a-how-to-tutorial/7107#7107 and then http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/. It's fine to post a tutorial, but you need to ask and answer it, Q&A style. If you want to do this, I will delete my answer, and let you get the reputation. Also, note that most people want to use free software, so if there is an alternative to EASEUS, please substitute that in.

Comment: Whitch one do I want to delete I don't want to mess any thing up I got "system " "hddrecovery " and my hdd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After installing Windows 7 or 8, you need to have a `logical partition` to install Ubuntu alongside it. If you don't have a logical partition then the option `Install Ubuntu alongside Windows` is missing.

To get it back, do the following.

1. Install [EASEUS Partition Master Professional Edition](http://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/epm-pro.html) (NB: Quite Expensive) or [free trial download here](http://easeus-partition-master-professional.en.softonic.com)
2. Run EASEUS Partition Master then click `Go to main screen` option.
3. Here, select the partition which you want to install Ubuntu in, and right-click on it and select `Delete Partition`. Now it's unallocated (Free space).
4. If you don't have this partition you can shrink another one other partition. Just right-click on other partition and select `Resize/Move Partition` (20GB is enough). Don't format the free space.
5. Now right-click on `* unallocated` and select `Create Partition`. Under the `Create as drop down`, select `Logical` and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.
6. Click the <kbd>Apply</kbd> button at the top of EASEUS window (under view menu) then click <kbd>Yes</kbd>. This operation needs to restart your computer to completing
7. Finish

If you insert the Ubuntu installation media (USB/DVD) you will see `Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7/8`.

Comment: You can get Easus Partition Master Free Edition. I used it for years on Windows.