# Dual boot data lost possibilities

Tags: dual-boot

DiskDrive has 4 partitions C: D: E: F: 
C: drive has Windows Xp and D: drive is completely free. How I can install UBUNTU 14.04 LTS on D: drive and which partition and mount type I should use ,so will my data lost on drive other E: and F:?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't install Ubuntu on D: drive. The D: drive is just a partition that Windows calls D:. Get rid of the D: partition and make a partition with the ext4 filesystem for Ubuntu. Turn the D: drive into free space THEN make the ext4 filesystem with the free space.

Comment: How to turn free space ,there are asking for select  drive to install and what type of partition and mount type and it will lost my another drive data ?

Comment: You only have one drive; C, D, E, and F are all partitions, not different drives.

Comment: I've done but as I thought root is taken D: drive but accidentally I keep E drive to swap and don't set size it takes whole drive to swap, I've lost E drive.

Comment: Wow I would have liked to know how that turned out, until I read this previous comment I was wondering where swap was going to do. You can in theory install Ubuntu on a single partition but it's not a good idea because we still want a swap partition and ideally at least separate /home from / There are solutions (at least up to Ubuntu 14) where you could install Ubuntu *alongside Windows, in the same partition!* May not always work but good to be aware of. Sorry you lost your E drive, shows the value of always reading the screen very carefully. And it's possible OP had multiple drives :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old quedtion but an answer was never accepted, and it misses an important point, **it's possible to install Ubuntu alongside Windows in the Windows partition.** Now I don't know if that includes a D drive or can only be done on the C drive but the Ubuntu install lives on the NTFS partition and (assuming sufficient free space) does not require any other partitioning.

[Here's an interesting question where the user does not see this option and why/how to fix it.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486703/how-to-install-ubuntu-alongside-windows-7-8)

[Here is a great question with a very technical long answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi),search for "alongside"

I am not certain this is an option any longer in Ubuntu 15 but for situations where Windows is on a logical partition it should be an option when installing Ubuntu 14.10.