# Windows 8/ Ubuntu Dual Installation Problem!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, partitioning, windows-8

Okay, so I have fulfilled all the requirements necessary to dual booting Ubuntu 14.04.1 on Windows 8 (disabling secure boot and fast boot, making liveCD, and partitioning 50gb of free space on my 2tb hard drive) but when I am at in the installation process of Ubuntu and the options to install appear the "install alongside ____" option does not appear at all, and when I reach the partitioning area of the installation, the only drive that appears in the list is a 16gb drive of which I do not know the origin. 
My question is: How do I make my drive containing my 50gb partition and OS appear in the manifested system driver list? Please help!
The device for boot loader installation is /dev/sda.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/486703/how-to-install-ubuntu-alongside-windows-7-8/486881#486881

Answer (score 0):

Download Gparted at http://gparted.org/ (it is free) . If "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows is missing" u need to have a logical partition to install Ubuntu alongside.  Boot with USB or CD with Gparted on it, and make the necessary changes.